# Elasticsearch support both case sensitive & insensitive

Tags: elasticsearch, elasticsearch-aggregation

**Setup:** Elasticsearch 6.3

I have an index that represents the products catalog.

Every document contains one product's data.

One of the fields called `categories` which is an array of strings - List of relevant categories.

99.9% of the queries are: give me the products that match categories A, B and C. The query about is case **insensitive**, thus categories mapping looks like:

```
"categories": {
    "type": "keyword",
    "normalizer": "lowercase_normalizer"
}
```

For reporting (0.1% of all queries) I need to return a list of all possible categories case **sensitive**!

Consider the following documents:

```
"_id": "product1",
"_source": {
    "categories": [
        "WOMEN",
        "Footwear"
     ]
}

"_id": "product2",
"_source": {
    "categories": [
        "Men",
        "Footwear"
     ]
}
```

Running the following query:

```
{
  "size": 0,
  "aggs": {
    "categories": {
      "terms": {
        "field": "categories",
        "size": 100
      }
    }
  }
}
```

return:

```
{
  "took": 2,
  "timed_out": false,
  "_shards": {
    "total": 1,
    "successful": 1,
    "skipped": 0,
    "failed": 0
  },
  "hits": {
    "total": 40453,
    "max_score": 0,
    "hits": [

    ]
  },
  "aggregations": { 
    "sterms#categories": {
      "doc_count_error_upper_bound": 0,
      "sum_other_doc_count": 12453,
      "buckets": [
        {
          "key": "men",
          "doc_count": 27049
        },
        {
          "key": "women",
          "doc_count": 21332
        },
       .........
      ]
    }
  }
}
```

Is there a way to return the categories with their case sensitivity (as stored in the documents)? I'm interested in `["WOMEN", "Men"]` in this query's result.

[The question in Elasticsearch discuss forum](https://discuss.elastic.co/t/elasticsearch-support-both-case-sensitive-insensitive/215686)

Thanks,
Itay

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you need to configure a field in your property that will not use any normalizer :

[Documentation on fields](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/multi-fields.html)

Something like

```
"categories": {
    "type": "keyword",
    "normalizer": "lowercase_normalizer",
    "fields": {
        "case_sensitive": {
            "type": "keyword"
        }
    }
}
```

Then make your aggregation on this field :

```
{
  "size": 0,
  "aggs": {
    "categories": {
      "terms": {
        "field": "categories.case_sensitive",
        "size": 100
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: I'll check that, thanks! will it impact my other queries? (not aggregation, filtering/term/must queries)

Comment: No side effects :) since your existing query will target the same field as before

Comment: I'm trying to solve it now. Should it cost me more than that? in terms of RAM / Storage?